# CSS file in a Spring WAR returns a 404

Tags: html, css, jsp, maven

I have a Java EE application that I am building with Spring and Maven. It has the usual project structure. Here is a bit of the hierarchy.

```
MyApplication
    src
        main
            webapp
                WEB-INF
                    layout
                        header.jsp
                styles
                    main.css
```

I want to include that CSS file in my JSP. I have the following tag in place.

```
<c:url var="styleSheetUrl" value="/styles/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${styleSheetUrl}">
```

When I deploy the application, the CSS page isn't being located. When I view the page source, the href is `/MyApplication/styles/main.css`. Looking inside the WAR, there is a `/styles/main.css`. However, I get a 404 when I try to access the CSS file directly in the browser.

I discovered that the reason for the issue was the Dispatcher Servlet mapping. The mapping looks as follows.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I imagine the Dispatcher Servlet doesn't know how to handle the CSS request. What is the best way to handle this issue? I would rather not have to change all of my request mappings.

Comment: Note: it's not the JSP who locates the CSS file. It's the webbrowser who does that after having retrieved and parsed the bunch of HTML produced by the JSP.

Comment: Edited. Was just righting fast ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to configure Spring to handle the [static resources](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources) (CSS, JS, images) separately from servlet requests to your app. To do this, configure your Spring config to map requests to static files via a separate top level directory (e.g. "static"):

```
<!-- Where to load static resources (css, js, images) -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/" />
```

Then change your JSP to use the path `/static/styles/main.css`.

Note, convention dictates you name your "styles" directory to "css".

Comment: +1 Thanks. Used `<mvc:resources mapping="/styles/**" location="/styles/" />` in my application context XML and it worked (I'll rework to use the static folder later).

Answer (score 4):

Add the following in web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and use the following to include your css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
```

Comment: It works! For any other type of static resources, related <servlet-mapping> should be added with appropriate <url-pattern>