# Loading images/css/javascript in a jsp/java ee web application

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsp, servlets

Today I just had my first class on Java ee and dynamic web project... and I have a question for you.

My teacher asked us to create a controller in an very basic mvc concept.

She gave us some code example and asked us to call a view from the controller. Ok, it works!
But then, if I try to add an image `<img src="images/img.jpg" />`, I think my controller re-route the folder images/img.jpg and well, my images/img.jpg is a type text in the file headers...

Any help would be appreciated...

Here is my servlet
**Controller.java**

```
package ca.qc.lacmegantic.ville;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Controller
 */
@WebServlet("/Controller")
public class Controller extends HttpServlet
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
 * methods.
 * 
 * @param request servlet request
 * @param response servlet response
 * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
 * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
 */
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    String urlCP = request.getRequestURI();

    String url = urlCP.substring(request.getContextPath().length());

    if (url.equals("/") || url.equals(""))
    {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/views/view.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    processRequest(request, response);
}

}
```

Here is my **web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ca.qc.lacmegantic.ville.Controller</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Here is my **view.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<img src="images/img.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

**Files Structure:**
[image: Files Structure]

Comment: Can you provide the file structure of where the images are stored in relation to the jsp?  It would help us assist you with the proper path for the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be mapping a front controller servlet on an URL pattern of `/`. This would override servletcontainer's "default" servlet which is responsible for serving static resources such as images. This is not what you want.

Map the controller on a more specific URL pattern such as `/pages/*` or something. Or maybe `/Controller`, exactly as you've there in the `@WebServlet` annotation which is actually not been registered at all because your `web.xml` is not declared conform Servlet 3.0.

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Controller</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Your another problem is that you've placed the image in `/WEB-INF` folder. The content in this folder is not publicly accessible. It's intented for JSP files only which are supposed to be forwarded or included by a front controller servlet or another JSP. Move the `/images` folder one level up, outside the `/WEB-INF` folder.

#### See also:

- [Our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - contains some hello world examples as well
- [Difference between / and /* in servlet mapping url pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140448/difference-between-and-in-servlet-mapping-url-pattern/)
- [Browser can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images and links when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316)
- [Moving resources under WEB-INF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088103)

Comment: I have updated my web.xml to be valid 3.0, but now when I call /Controller I obtain a white page, any idea what could cause this?

Comment: The nonsensicial `if()` block in the servlet is indeed causing that. Remove it. Don't forget to take time to go carefully through the "See also" links to better understand the one and other.

Comment: Nice! Thank you @BalusC XD Thank you! One last question, how would I redirect localhost/myproject to localhost/myproject/controller ?

Comment: I see that you've posted a new question about it. I've answered it.