# What is the url for an Eclipse Dynamic Web project's jsp files?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, configuration, web

I have added a dynamic web project in Eclipse and can access the static HTML files and resources in the WebContent folder.  I have placed my JSP files in WebConent\WEB-INF

This works fine:  "http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/index.htm"

This tells me the resource is not found: "http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/Logon.jsp"

I have not defined any JSP servlet mappings.  I have the default web.xml which only has the welcome files in it.  I right click the project name and choose Debug On Server to run the app.

Update: I've had some success.  I added the following to the Eclipse project's web.xml (in the WebContent\WEB-INF folder).  The Test.jsp works as  "http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/Test.jsp" only when Test.jsp is in the WebContent folder and not when its in the WebContent\WEB-INF folder.

```
  <servlet>
   <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>fork</param-name>
       <param-value>false</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
       <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
       <param-value>false</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
        <param-name>logVerbosityLevel</param-name>
        <param-value>WARNING</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
```

```
   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Do you have a Logon.jsp.  Does the logs show any problem?

Comment: Yes Logon.jsp is there.  I removed all files and have only a Test.jsp in the WEB-INF folder and that has 1 line of text in it.  There's no logs in the tomacat\logs folder.  Should I be looking elsewhere for logs?

Comment: There is this warning in the console window:

WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:HelloWorld' did not find a matching property.

Answer (score 2):

Files in `/WEB-INF` are not publicly accessible. That folder is intented for configuration files, template files, tag files, include files, MVC view files, etcetera. Basically everything which is *not* supposed to be *directly* accessible by the enduser without invoking some main JSP file or a front controller servlet first.

Just put them outside the `/WEB-INF` folder, in the public webcontent.

#### See also:

- [Moving resources under WEB-INF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088103/moving-resources-under-web-inf)

---

Don't forget to remove the unnecessary copy of the `JspServlet` from your `web.xml`. It didn't solve the concrete problem at all. Even more, it really doesn't belong there in your webapp's `web.xml`. It is already definied in servletcontainer's own `web.xml` (in case of Tomcat you can find it in its `/conf` folder. Registering the `JspServlet` in your webapp's `web.xml` would only make your webapp unportable. It wouldn't be able to run on a servletcontainer of a different make than Tomcat.

Comment: Perfect! It worked. I originally had all the files in a sub folder of WebContent and moved them to WEB-INF but was given advise to move them into WEB-INF.  Thanks for the help.